# Docker Service fabric Debug Mode must be 'Refresh Application'

Tags: asp.net, docker-compose, azure-service-fabric

I get this message when containerizing an Asp.net Web API

Warning: Application Debug Mode must be 'Refresh Application' to build required Docker images on project load. Current Application Debug Mode is 'Remove Application'.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is set the Debug mode to "Refresh Application".

To set the Application Debug Mode property

- On the Service Fabric application project's (.sfproj) shortcut menu, choose **Properties* (or press the F4 key).
- In the Properties window, set the Application Debug Mode property to "Refresh Application"

See more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio

By default, when an application is containerised, all its files are copied to the image.

To make debugging with edit and continue available inside the container this process is changed to mount a volume in the container mapped to a local folder in the host where the application can be changed, so that any changes to the application does not need an image rebuild.